# Build Android with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android

I am trying to build android from the source code, and I was following the steps from

```
https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html
```

It looks like I built it successfully. However, after I installed the system to my Nexus 7 by

```
fastboot flashall -w
```

Did anybody encounter the similar problem? Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What error you getting ? or waht your probem if it is buil succesfully

Comment: It looks like I cannot comment to my post. The problem is after I built and installed the system to Nexus 7, it reboot and then freezes at the page shows Google logo.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the driver. After I re-extract the drivers and re-compile, re-flash it. Now my nexus 7 can start. But I encounter another problem, that is the Google play service cannot start successfully.

Comment: Just to avoid confusing anyone else, that would be the proprietary binary-only drivers which typically have to be added to the AOSP sources to get a working build.  Leaving them out can indeed result in this type of boot hang.  As for the Google Play Services issue, that really doesn't belong as a question in your answer, but the problem there is fundamentally the Google Play Services is not part of the Android Open Source Project, but rather something that is only available by negotiating a license with Google.